# Template is missing in RoR App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I created an app "guestbook" in rails, I then created a controller  using "rails g controller entries". After that I created index.html in app/views/entries/  and in it I wrote following :-

```
 <h1>Hello <%= @name %></h1>
<%= form_tag :action => 'sign_in' do %>
<p>Enter your name:
<%= text_field_tag 'visitor_name', @name %></p>
<%= submit_tag 'Sign in' %>
<% end %>
```

and in entries_controller.rb it is written :-

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
    def sign_in
        @name = params[:visitor_name]
    end
end
```

after that when I run "rails s"
and go to :-

```
localhost:3000/entries/
```

it shows me a proper view which is supposed to be there.

when I enter the name and press button it routes to `localhost:3000/entries/sign_in` and it says the following error :-

Template is missing

Missing template entries/sign_in, application/sign_in with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/redblink/rbtest/guestbook/app/views"

please let me know what is happening ???

Comment: Well just create a view `entries/sign_in.html.erb` for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix:**

This error is occurred because rails server is unable to find template with name `sign_in.html.erb` in `app/views/entries` directory. You should create it.

**Explanation:**

By default rails tries to find template with same name as your action has i.e. sign_in in your case. If you don't want to create or render this default template, you need to specify another template to render by using `render` method in your action. `render` method is defined in ActionController::Base class

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a ERB template in `/home/redblink/rbtest/guestbook/app/views/sign_in.html.erb` with the contents you want to show to the user.