# Missing Template Creating New View Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I followed a rails tutorial [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) that has you create a simple blog as an introduction to rails. Now, I'd like to add another page, but I am having some trouble.

So, I have a page that lists all the blog articles located in apps\view\articles\index.html.erb. The code looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Preview</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text[0,20] %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Read more...', article_path(article) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Now, I want to add a link on that page called "Backend" which is an exact duplicate of the page in the code above except it has "Backend" as the header (I will add different functionalities separately to that page later).

1. Above the table in index.html.erb, I wrote:
2. In app\views\articles, I created a backend.html.erb file that is an exact duplicate of the index.html.erb file.

3.In app\helpers, I created a backend_helper.rb with the following code:

```
module BackendHelper
end
```

4.In app\controllers, I created a duplicate of the Articles controller in the tutorial, except I changed the class to:

```
class BackendController < ApplicationController
```

5.And in my routes.rb file, I added a get for backend:

```
  root 'welcome#index'

    resources :articles do
        root 'articles#index'
    end

    resources :articles do
        resources :comments
    end
get 'backend', to: 'backend#index'
```

**Problem:** 
Now, when I click on the link,I get the following error:

```
Missing template backend/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "C:/tutorialpath/app/views"
```

I read about a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778802/template-is-missing-in-ror-app), but it seems like the answer was to create a new html.erb file in the app/views folder (for this project, it is in apps/views/articles) which I did. Does anyone have any other suggestions or see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are routing to backend#index (You are calling the `index` method in your `BackendController`), your html.erb file needs to be `index.html.erb` in a `backend` folder : `backend/index.html.erb`

Answer (score 1):

You can *explicitly* render any view from your controller like so:

```
class BackendController
  def index
   @articles = Article.all
   render 'articles/index'
  end
end
```

Instead of Rails *implicit* rendering that looks for `controller/action.{format}.[erb|slim|haml|jbuilder]`. So in this case `backend/index.html.erb`.

But, in this case you may want to use separate views and use partials to extract reusable chunks.

app/views/acticles/_article.html.erb:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= article.title %></td>
  <td><%= article.text[0,20] %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Read more...', article_path(article) %></td>
</tr>
```

Note that the file name starts with an underscore, that denotes that the file is a partial and not a complete view.

app/views/acticles/index.html.erb:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Preview</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
  <%= render @articles %>
</table>
```

app/views/backend/index.html.erb:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Preview</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
  <%= render @articles %>
</table>
```

`<%= render @articles %>` loops though the articles and renders the partial for each - magic! Its equivalent to this:

```
<% @articles.each do |a| %>
  <%= render partial: 'articles/article', article: a %>
<% end %>
```

Now you can take this a step further and extract the whole table into a partial as well.

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials